# Why is calling .at() is much slower than .deployed()?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, dapp-development

I'm trying to create a helper function that will allow me to switch between a `.deployed()` call to my contract, vs one with a fixed address using `.at()`. The second call (that is commented out in the code below), is so extremely slow. I'm making about 1-2 calls per second (polling for an event) against a local testnet and it keeps Chrome pegged at 100% using the second method. The first method is about 20 times faster. Why is this so, and how do I fix this?

```
getContractDeploy: function() {
    contract_deploy = App.contracts.CONTRACTX.deployed();
    //contract_deploy = App.contracts.CONTRACTX.at(contract_address);
  return contract_deploy;
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using truffle, then you are using [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) to manage contracts.

Looking at the implementation of [`at`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/e6e93681150b834d003428197dc10702ac38fe83/contract.js#L383), it makes an extra call to [`web3.eth.getCode`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/e6e93681150b834d003428197dc10702ac38fe83/contract.js#L398) to ensure there's a contract at the provided address.

The implementation of [`deployed`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/e6e93681150b834d003428197dc10702ac38fe83/contract.js#L414) is simpler and it only relies on the information from the contract's artifact.

It is not a good idea to have `.at()` called at the hot path, or at least cache the result if the address is not changing frequently.

Comment: If you don't want the check then I guess you could fake a json artifact in memory and use it to instantiate the contract with `deployed()`...